# GPS receiver uart buffer line break

Tags: gps, buffer, line, stm32, uart

I am trying to read the whole stream of messsages from my gps receiver, i need some sort of recognition for end of stream, between one block of messages and the next.

I've tried to read into a buffer with various dimensions (100, 200, 500, 1000) and obviously if is too short I break messages, if is too long i find same block of messages repeated, example:

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC 
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
```

That is what i'd like to receive for every interrupt on receive (with HAL_UART_ReveiveIT() for example, but also in other platforms the concept is the same).

Instead, regarding the size of the buffer that i give, i have data like:

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXX
```

or

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXX
```

or

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXX
```

I am not able to detect the end of a block of message, that will repeat again, like:

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
```

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
```

```
GNGGA,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGNS,XXXXXXXX*CC
GNRMC,XXXXXXXXXXX*CC
GNGSV,XXXXXXXXXX*CC
```

I've tried to detect interrupt on received char, so checking if current char is '\r' or '\n', but **this works for every line, it detects only the end of a line, not the end of a block**.

I would like to read from the uart, with interrupt on complete receive or interrupt on DMA, only the complete block of messages, and read again the next block, but **I can't find any flag or termination character that can help me to distiguish between blocks**.

Also, the block can have different size depending on the data of every message, so I can't give a fixed length array.

I was thinking about *hw flow control* or to use the fix LED signal from gps to send an external interrupt that can trigger the end of the block...

- Do you have any idea?
- It's all a matter of post processing with a parser?
- Maybe discarding or overwriting fields found in multiple sentences of the same kind?

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"It's all a matter of post processing with a parser?"* -- Correct, otherwise you're trying to do too much at interrupt level and the UART driver.  There is no concept of lines or blocks to a UART, only frames of single character.  There are break conditions and timing pauses between frames (e.g. Modbus), but those occur completely under the control of the sender.

Comment: Thanks sawdust, I was hoping something more could be done interrupt side, but apparently is not the case. Cheers

Comment: Is it this protocol: http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/content/NMEA_Format_v0.1.pdf ? If so, you *really* should be just parsing messages by the CR+LF at the end of each message. It's going to be much more robust than splitting the data to messages by other means (e.g. using IDLE interrupt).

Answer (score 0):

Since what you posted as the Output from your GPS receiver seems to have always the same structure and most importent same lenght I would suggest yout to count the UART messegas that you received.

If that is not the case and the lenght of your lines vary due to the suppression of leading zeros you could as well count the lines witch you told you can allready identify.

If even the length of the block varys since your blocks seem to start witch `GNGGA` you could trigger on the line ends to minimise the interrupt load (even better if you configer your UART interface with caracter match) and onve you find a line starting witch `GNGGA` you know every line before that one in your buffer is one block.

When you know exactly how long a block is you can let DMA do the work of counting for you and generate an interrupt of set a fleg once the configred number of bytes is in your buffer. This would give you a selfmade "EndOfBlock" flag/interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I would not care so much about detecting end of block directly in the UART receiver code.

I would rather let the UART receiver use a circular buffer.
Have a simple parser trying to find each line in the circular buffer as it fills up, and forward one and one line the (NMEA) parser.

And let the NMEA parser store up data as it receives data, until a complete message has been received, and then forward this to your main program flow.

(so basically, make some simple layers, and each layer should be easy to debug, as it is only responsible for one task)